# Apple ZoomingPDFViewer PDF Position

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf

I have a Problem with [Apple´s ZoomingPDFViewer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer/Introduction/Intro.html), I didn't get how to change the Position of the PDF in the ScrollView, because every PDF I load has a big white border on the top still left. I tried to change the ScrollView Position but it doesn't affect the Problem.

[image]